# Android web view url desin broken

Tags: android, webview

My web view is loading an external url.
External website is loaded but with alignment issues.
But the  same url loads perfectly in iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to fix these two properties of the `WebView` from settings

```
WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
    browser.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    browser.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```